# specify annotate field on subtables

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I have a parent table `Image` and subtable `Resized_image`, so I have stored `images` data in `resized_image` table. I want to filter the data using aspect ratio.

This is my model:

```
 class Image(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=False)
 class Resized_image(models.Model):
        img = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image=models.ImageField(upload_to=config.date_format,width_field='width', height_field='height',)
        width=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=False, editable=False)
        height=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=False, editable=False)
        size=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False,editable=False)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='inserted')

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'resized_images'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.status

    def save(self,force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        if not self.image:
            return  

        super(Resized_image, self).save()
        self.size = os.stat(str(self.image)).st_size
        super(Resized_image, self).save()
```

This is my view:

```
class ImagePostAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = imagesSerializer

def get(self, request):
        print("inside get views.py")
        return super(mixins.CreateModelMixin,self).get(request)
def myfilter(self, queryset, queryparam, queryarg):
        param = self.request.query_params.get(queryparam, None)
        #print("param",param)
        if param is not None:
            try:
                newarg = {queryarg : int(param)}
                #print("newarg",newarg)
                queryset = queryset.filter(**newarg)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        return queryset
def get_queryset(self):
 queryset = Image.objects.all() 
 queryset = self.myfilter(queryset, 'minheight', 'images__height__gte')
        queryset = self.myfilter(queryset, 'maxheight', 'images__height__lte')
```

here I am filtering data in `GET` request using `minheight` which is present in `Resized_image` table similarly I want to filter data using aspect ratio i.e., I want to add `aspect_ratio` field using `table_name.objects.annotate` and then filter the data... How can i do that??

Comment: what will be the value aspect_ratio  ?

Comment: http://10.75.12.175:7005/images/?aspect_ratio=1 
http://10.75.12.175:7005/images/?aspect_ratio=16/9
http://10.75.12.175:7005/images/?aspect_ratio=1.77777778

I can pass any of the format it should calculate the aspect_ratio based on height and width present in Resized_image table and then give the results

Comment: added answer i think that will work, for second url